# Helpmenu in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I recently completed my application and now I want to create a user guide for (for each tab) this app which explain some part and **will appear first 3 to 4 times**  when the application runs. After that when the user uses this application the guide will not seen. For detail they have to go a help tab which is there in my aplication.

So Is it possible to display a help menu for First 3 or 4 times when the app is run? If it is possible, then can someone please give me some reference or solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store a value in NSUserDefaults and increment this value on start. After hitting the third/fourth start don't display the help menu any more.

```
// start
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger numStarts = [defaults integerForKey:@"numStarts"];
if (numStarts < 4) {
    // show help menu
} 
[defaults setInteger:numStarts+1 forKey:@"numStarts"];
[defaults synchronize];
```